# offering mysql on localhost via a ssh layer

Tags: linux, ssh, localhost

I have 2 machines: One has a mysql server that runs on localhost.The second one has no mysql server. I want to access the mysql server from the first machine on the second machine also on localhost. It should be something like a virtual localhost.

The first machine should log in the second machine via secure socket and should emulate the server there somehow.
Is something like this possible, how is it called , and how does it work.
Is this what is called a tunnel?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, this is what is called a [tunnel](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding).

Assuming host A is running the mysql server and host B is the one that dose not.

To create the tunnel enter the following on host B:

```
ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 username@A
```

(Add `-f -N` to the command to not execute any command on the remote host and immediately background the ssh connection).

This creates a listening port `3306` on host B which is forwarded over the ssh tunnel to `localhost:3306` on host A.

Now just run `mysql` on host B and you should be able to connect to the mysql server on host A.

Hope it helps!